# Inverse in a functional space

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to understand why the inverse of a bounded operator must to be bounded too? In other context, all bijective function have an inverse but when we deal with a bounded operator it have to be bounded too. Thank your time.

My question is why an "unbounded inverse" is not an inverse? Why it have to be bounded/continuous?

Comment: Well, one proof for Banach spaces is base on the open mapping theorem.

Comment: I know it! My question is why the operator be bijective is note sufficient to be invertible? Why we have to prove that the bilateral inverse is continuous/bounded?

Comment: Well, in a Banach space you have no choice. In other space an unbounded inverse would be fine, just not continuous.

Comment: I think copper.hat understood my point. But copper.hat why we don't have choice? Why the continuity/bounded is necessary to be an inverse? The definition could be only that an operator, to be invertible, have to be bijective. But they put one more restriction: the operator, to be an inverse, it have to be bounded/continuous! And I don't understand why they impose this restriction

Comment: When you talk about invertibility, you must define the class of objects from which the inverse comes. If you are discussing bounded operators $B$, then it makes sense to discuss the inverse coming from bounded operators, too. But nothing is etched in stone.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it is like an algebraic imposition. Have you an idea why he called the bilateral inverse of formal inverse, when we still don't know if the inverse is bounded?

Comment: An inverse of a bounded linear operator on a Banach space is still an inverse; it's just that an unbounded inverse is not defined everywhere on the space, but only on the range of the operator. It's still an inverse. However, the word invertible is usually reserved for having a bounded inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this setting boundedness and continuity are equivalent.

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $A:X \rightarrow Y $ a linear, bijective and bounded operator. Since $A$ is bounded it is also continuous. Now you could use the open mapping theorem to prove that also the inverse $A^{-1}$ is continuous, and hence bounded.

Edit: The result is valid only if the spaces are Banach, otherwise you can find counterexamples of linear and bounded mappings with inverses that are unbounded. For example the identity mapping

$$ C([0,1],|| \cdot ||_{1} ) \ni x \rightarrow x \in C([0,1],|| \cdot ||_{\infty}) $$

Comment: Thank you. I know this, but my question is different. I would like to know why if the operator is bijective I cannot consider it invertible? Why I have to prove that the bilateral inverse is continuous/bounded?

Comment: My question is why an unbounded inverse is not an inverse?

Comment: Why can't you consider the operator invertible if it is bijective?

Comment: The bounded inverse theorem says something about a property of the inverse, if the operator is between Banach spaces. So if you have an operator between Banach spaces, and you manage to find an inverse, you are guaranteed that it will be bounded/continuous.

Comment: Because the definition of inverse in the context of functional analysis is that the operator is invertible iff it has an left inverse, a right inverse and it have to be bounded. The open mapping theorem, for example, is necessary to prove that the inverse is bounded, because, by hypotheses, the operator is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: Okay I understand why you are confused, where is the definition from?

Comment: I am studying the Rynne/Youngson book on functional analysis, do you know?